# Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Accept Suggestion" in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I do a lot of reviewing suggestions in Google Docs and I have the cursor "within" suggested text and would like to accept/reject the suggestion with a keyboard shortcut.

From what I can tell there is currently no keyboard shortcut for this, despite there being a menu item, but I am hoping to confirm this and document that it's missing.

#### Menu item "Accept Suggestion"

If you use the menu search (`option+/`) while the cursor is inside a suggestion, an **Accept Suggestion** item is available, and selecting it does what I expect it to. Unfortunately there is no keyboard shortcut displayed for it.

#### Other keyboard shortcuts for suggestions

As we can see, there are shortcuts to start reviewing, and to navigate between suggestions, but no way to directly accept or reject them

[image: Screenshot of the keyboard shortcuts for reviewing suggestions and jumping to the next and previous suggestions]

#### Is there a way to create a shortcut for this based on the menu item?

I'm happy to either be proven wrong ("there IS a shortcut") or to be explained that there is some way to take advantage of the menu item and add a shortcut for myself.

Comment: Another non-ideal way: open context menu `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`\ `, navigate down `▼`, accept ⏎ (on MacOS: `Cmd` instead of `Ctrl`)

Comment: Good point. That's so much fussy work that I'd probably rather use the mouse, but in terms of a keyboard-only solution, I think it's actually the best answer :(

Comment: Hurray! Google added `Tab` as a shortcut!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> on MacOS, then down arrow to tab through suggestions

Comment: Thanks! How did you find it? Is there some documentation out there?

Comment: @boldnik, It's associated with "Context (right-click) menu" in the [Google Docs keyboard shortcut page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738).

Comment: Anything for gmail auto complete / auto correct type suggestions?

Comment: `Tab` + `Enter`, found in [Answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/144222/303561), is the fastest way to accept inline suggestions and is cross-platform compatible.

Comment: I had to put my keyboard in Canadian English (and press `Cmd`+`shift`+`\` (which is letter `à` on my keyboard)). But this opens the 'right-click menu only'. I don't know if this is supposed to be happening, but it's not getting to the inline suggestion. At least on Safari. I need to click on the suggestion box and then I can us `tab`. But then I need to click the other boxes again... Not sure if there is a way to cycle through all the suggestion and accept them.

Comment: Quick update: if I press `Cmd`+`Ctrl`+`O`+`U`, then I can use tab to cycle through the `Suggested Edits` box. But for every comment, I need to redo the `Cmd`+`Ctrl`+`O`+`U` danse on the keyboard, because after accepting a comment, the focus goes back to the text

Answer (score 13):

## Update: Hurray! Google added the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button as a shortcut!

Outdated answer:

You can also use the shortcut for reviewing *all* suggestions in the document:

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Return</kbd> to accept.

On macOS:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Return</kbd> to accept.

Answer (score 4):

When your cursor is at or in the offending word or phrase you will see the suggestion - if you want it simply press Tab (to highlight the suggestion) and enter to use the suggestion. So Tab>Enter.

Comment: This is by far the right answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to accept the one suggestion for your immediate context, and you're on the word to be corrected, and the pop-up is present, i.e.

[image]

you can then use (in Windows) Ctrl+Alt+E Ctrl+Alt+P to move the focus to the popup (the suggestion will be highlighted in light blue) and then use Enter to accept the suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed. Doesn't seem to work for gmail though, got something for gmail suggestions?

Comment: For gmail on Windows Tab highlights the popup, then Enter accepts the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Linux, PC) the shortest sequence was to press "Context menu" button ([this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)), "Down", and "Enter" to accept the top suggestion. I can do it without taking my hands of the default position.